# pattern match for for date with symbol and end symbol

Tags: java, regex

I am getting an id in request with date in a specific format and no of hits they have tried on my API and if its last hit of that day then in form of string as an end.
my variable is

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{8}_.*", message = "Field 'batchId' invalid.please provide in format yyyyMMdd_<digit/end>")
    private String batch Id;
```

for example `20200509_001` for the first try or `20200509_9999999` for 9999999 hits ie format yyyyMMdd_no_of_tries
or `20200509_end` ie yyyyMMdd_end for the last hit of the day (this end can be case insensitive.)
but 1 of them must be there, either no_of_tries or end `20200509_` this is invalid.

I need to prepare a pattern for this., so far I have come up `"^\\d{8}_.*"` it matches up to 8 digits, but I am not able to match digits or string after the _.

Comment: Why not `s.split("_")`?

Comment: i tried but it was failing, can you give me exact pattern please what you are saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this pattern:

```
^\d{8}_(\d+|end)$
```

This forces having digits or *end* at the end.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eUJYeb/3)

In your code:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{8}_(\\d+|end)$", message = "Field 'batchId' invalid.please provide in format yyyyMMdd_<digits/end>")
    private String batch Id;
```

In case you want the end case insensitive:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{8}_(\\d+|[Ee][Nn][Dd])$", message = "Field 'batchId' invalid.please provide in format yyyyMMdd_<digits/end>")
    private String batch Id;
```